# How to use UnitTest++ installed with apt in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, testing, unittest++

```
$ sudo apt install libunittest++-dev
```

After that

```
$ sudo find / -iname "*UnitTest++.*" 2> /dev/null
/usr/include/UnitTest++/UnitTest++.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/UnitTest++.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libUnitTest++.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libUnitTest++.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libUnitTest++.so.2.0.0
```

But there's no `libUnitTest++.a` as I have in Windows where I compiled UnitTest++ myself according the instructions [here](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp/wiki/Building-Using-CMake). Also I don't see the source code files.

Can I use this installation for my testing or need to download the sources and compile them myself? Or how can I use `libUnitTest++.so` instead of `libUnitTest++.a`?

Here is one of my tests:

```
#include "UnitTest++/UnitTest++.h"
#include "skip_list.cpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

TEST(NodeTest) 
{
    SkipListNode<int> node(15, 2);

    CHECK_EQUAL(15, node.key);
    CHECK_EQUAL(2, node.height);
    CHECK(!node.next[0]);
    CHECK(!node.next[1]);
    CHECK(!node.next[2]);
}

int main(int, const char *[])
{
   return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
}
```

Now it says:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g  skip_list_test.cpp
/tmp/cc2zCui4.o: In function `TestNodeTest::RunImpl() const':
/home/greg/study/data_structures/02_03_01_skip_list/skip_list_test.cpp:16: undefined reference to `UnitTest::CurrentTest::Details()'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you did in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61135195/363), you need to tell `g++` to include the library. There, you provide it with the full path to the `libUnitTest++.a` archive file that you compiled yourself as an input.

To use the library installed by your system package manager -- in this case, `apt` -- it would be more common to provide a linker directive. In this case, `-l UnitTest++` instructs the linker to "search my system library paths for `libUnitTest++.so`"

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g  skip_list_test.cpp -l UnitTest++ -o skip_list_test.out
$ ./skip_list_test.out
Success: 1 tests passed.
Test time: 0.00 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick! What do you mean by "system-installed library"? My solution was removing UnitTest++ deb-packages and compiling the sources from GitHub. Before, deb-packages installed `libUnitTest++.so` and no `libUnitTest++.a`. Do you mean `-l UnitTest++` would let me compile and run my test without `libUnitTest++.a` but with only `libUnitTest++.so`?

Comment: @user10815638 The system installed library is from the .deb package you installed originally and subsequently removed. Patrick is suggesting that you try the `-l UnitTest++` directive with that package installed.

Comment: @user10815638 by "system-installed library", I mean libraries installed via your system package manager, in this case `apt`. I'll clarify this in the answer. `-l UnitTest++` tells the linker to look for `libUnitTest++.so` in system library paths.

Comment: Thanks, guys! Yes, my own answer doesn't formally answers the initial question, but when stuck I preferred to get something working. Probably it would be better to use ``libUnitTest++.so`` as it's precompiled and hope it'll work. Just need some time to cope with existing installation. Need to remove or somehow deactivate ``libUnitTest++.a``.

Comment: @user10815638 if this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer for the benefit of all users of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, couldn't find time for testing. Now the check is done--the solution works!

Answer (score 0):

As there's no answer, removed the UnitTest++ deb-packages:

```
$ sudo apt remove libunittest++2 libunittest++-dev
```

Cloned the Git project and compiled it according the instructions above. Now it works:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g  -c -I/usr/local/include/ skip_list_test.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g  skip_list_test.o /usr/local/lib/libUnitTest++.a -o skip_list_test.out
./skip_list_test.out
Success: 2 tests passed.
Test time: 0.00 seconds.
```

And as for the installed artifacts:

```
$ sudo find / -iname "*UnitTest++.*" 2> /dev/null
/usr/local/include/UnitTest++/UnitTest++.h
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/UnitTest++.pc
/usr/local/lib/libUnitTest++.a
```

Anyway any other answers are welcome :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using this method to include UnitTest++ in your build, but I will point out it does not answer the specific question, which is "How to use UnitTest++ installed with apt in Ubuntu".